# Android Bound services: Inter vs Intra - app communication using Messenger

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, android-binder, android-messaging

I have 2 Android apps - **App1** and **App2**. I have a bound service - **ServiceA** in **App1**. Multiple services and activities in **App1** bind to **ServiceA** and call methods on it. Now, I want to send data from **ServiceA** to a remote service that exists in **App2**. I will be using the [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Messenger) API to expose the **binder** object from **ServiceA** for inter-process-communication.

From what I understand, all the activities and services dependent on **ServiceA** in **App1** will also now need to use the `Messenger` API to access the binder. Is this correct?

If yes, is there a way to make changes only to **ServiceA** so that it can exchange data with the remote service without making changes to it's existing clients?

P.S: The service doesn't need to handle multiple concurrent requests which is one of the main reasons I decided to go with the `Messenger` API.

Comment: What are you returning from `onBind()` now? Do your clients use AIDL to call methods in the `Service` now?

Comment: Since you want to send data from `ServiceA` to `ServiceB`, you should only need to implement the `Messenger` API in one direction (ie: `ServiceA` will bind to `ServiceB` and be a client of that `Service`, not the other way around). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidWasser ServiceA's existing clients include Activities and other Services from App1. `onBind` returns a binder created from extending the `Binder` class.

Comment: @DavidWasser App2 is new and will have ServiceB that needs to exchange data with ServiceA. ServiceA will expose a binder using the `Messenger` framework. - This is clear to me.

Existing clients of ServiceA in App1 bind to it and call some methods on it directly. If ServiceA is to use `Messenger`, my understanding is that the existing clients will no longer be able to invoke the methods directly but have to create a `Messenger` object using the binder they receive in `onServiceConnection` and pass `Message`s whenever they need to exchange/get data from ServiceA. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to provide both a `Messenger` based interface and a direct interface. I've not tested this myself, but you can try this:

In `onBind()` you receive an `Intent`. This is the `Intent` that the client used when calling `bindService()`. You can use 2 different ACTIONs (or use "extra"s) in the `Intent` so that you can differentiate between the calls from App1's clients and App2's clients. Then just return either a `Messenger` based `Binder` or your current implementation, depending on which client has called `onBind()`.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: That worked, thanks! I used intent actions to differentiate between the clients.